# What do I need to do to input that is only used for comparison purposes? If anything

Tags: php, forms, user-input

I may be asking(searching) this wrong  but I didn't find the answer elsewhere so here it is.

In a form(`$_POST`) we have a `RetypePassword` & `UserPassword` fields. `RetypePassword` is only used for comparison to `UserPassword`. `UserPassword` will be later hashed and stored. `RetypePassword` will be discarded.

It should probably be obvious but I am just not seeing it, so... Is there anything I should do to `RetypePassword` before trying to compare it against `UserPassword`?

Comment: If you are doing anything to the password *before* you check it (which is unlikely, and even discouraged), you need to do the same thing to the password verification. Other than that, no. You just want to make sure you're comparing apples to apples. Comparison should come first, then hashing of the password (and disregard the verification once it's verified), then storing it. In that order.

Comment: @Mike Thank you! I was thinkng that but I have had so much thrown at me with this code I am not sure I can think straight anymore!

Comment: No problem. To add to the things thrown at you (if it hasn't already) be sure you're [hashing correctly](http://php.net/password_hash) and not using something like md5 or sha1.

Comment: @Mike I am believe I am($hash = password_hash($userpswd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);) Though I may bcrypt it instead of default, I just haven't got to that part of this mess yet. ;)

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. `password_hash()` currently uses bcrypt by default and that's the recommended way to hash passwords..